# Error al sincronizar base de datos oracle con entity framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Al actualizar el modelo de base de datos para que coja los cambios del esquema de la base de datos me muestra este error:

> Se produjo una excepción de tipo **System.ArgumentException** al intentar actualizar desde la base de datos. El mensaje de la excepción es: No se puede convertir la cadena de conexión en tiempo de ejecución a su equivalente en tiempo de diseño. Las bibliotecas necesarias para que Visual Studio se comunique con la base de datos para tareas de diseño (proveedor DDEX) no están instaladas para el proveedor **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client**. Cadena de conexión: `DATA SOURCE=ooo.ccc.int:1521/orr;PASSWORD=SOCIO;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=true;USER ID=SOCIO`

He realizado una conexión a este esquema desde el explorador de servidores y no hay problema.

Comment: Lo siento, me pensaba que estba en stackoverflow inglés. Traducido

Comment: Suele pasar, no te preocupes :)

Comment: Hmm..en el mensaje de error veo que pone `PERSIST SECURITU INFO`. No tendras un error tipografico en la connection string y debería ser `PERSIST SECURITY INFO`?

Comment: error tipográfico, es PERSIST SECURITY INFO

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo tienes un `.edmx` que quieres actualizar

En el proyecto donde se encuentra el `.edmx` deberias tener un `app.config` donde se define el connection string de la forma que este lo requiere

La forma es algo como esto:

```
<add name="Northwind_Entities"  
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Northwind.csdl|  
                                res://*/Northwind.ssdl|  
                                res://*/Northwind.msl;  
                       provider=System.Data.SqlClient;  
                       provider connection string=  
                           &quot;Data Source=.\sqlexpress;  
                                 Initial Catalog=Northwind;  
                                 Integrated Security=True;  
                                 MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"  
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

lo explica en el titulo "Database/Model First with connection string in app.config/web.config file"

[Connection strings and models](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/connection-strings)

debes validar que lo defines de esa forma en el `.config` del proyecto donde esta el `edmx`

A donde apunto es que no se trata de un conenction string simple, sino que el `edmx` requiere esos `metadata` para poder resolver el modelo